# Undefined index: firmName

Tags: php, session

```
<input class="span8 validate[required]" type="text" name="mobile" 
      id="mobile" value="<?=$_SESSION['emailId']?>" />

<input class="span8 validate[required]" type="text" name="firmName" 
      id="firmName" value="<?=$_SESSION['firmName']?>" />
```

when ever iam trying to do this it arises an error please help me

only one field is coming

Not coming

Comment: There is no `firmName` in the session. Please post the code where you set it.

Comment: You don't have `firmName` in your session.Did you see what it's showing var_dump($_SESSION)?

Comment: the email field only coming. all other fields are error

Answer (score 2):

If there isnt firmName in the session it would raise error.

Solution would be index checking.

```
<input class="span8 validate[required]" type="text" name="mobile"   
  id="mobile" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['emailId'])) echo $_SESSION['emailId']; ?>" />
```

Comment: @sachin Meaning that there is nothing stored in `$_SESSION['emailId']`. You need to set it!

Comment: You should set this on form submit, as you did to emailId.

Comment: function getContactLists($emailId)
{
 $result = array();
 $emailId = mysql_escape_string($emailId);
 $tableName = 'tbl_organisation';
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_organisation where emailId='".$emailId."'";
 echo $sql;
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
 {
  $result[] = $row;
 }
 return $result;
}

Comment: what happens before you call this function? E.g. where is $_SESSION["emailId"]=$_POST["emailId"]? If there is not, you would need to do after POST.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` and check what elements are in there. It seems that there is no such element as `firmName` in there.

To avoid such notice, do an `isset` before using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Think about such a function like this (simplified):

```
<?php
function displayValue(&$variable) {
  if(isset($variable)) {
    return $variable;
  }
}
?>
```

And use it like this:

```
<input class="span8 validate[required]" type="text" name="firmName" 
      id="firmName" value="<?php echo(displayValue($_SESSION['firmName'])); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your error_reporting level, this will cause errors if $_SESSION['firstname'] does not exist.